# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while performing strcat using pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, coredump, c-strings

I am relatively new to C. Now I know Segmentation fault appears when we try to use memory which we don't have access to. But I fail to find out where am I going wrong and would like to know. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char *str1 = "United";
char *str2 = "Front";
char *str3;

int l1,l2,l3;
l1 = strlen(str1)+1;
l2 = strlen(str2)+1;
l3 = l1 + l2; 

str3 = (char *)malloc(l3);
str3 = strcat(str1,str2);

printf("%s\n",str3);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char *str1 ;
  char *str2 ;
  char *str3;
  int l1,l2,l3;
  str1  = (char*)malloc(10);
  str2  = (char*)malloc(10);
  strcpy(str1,"United" );
  strcpy(str2,"Front" );

  l1 = strlen(str1)+1;
  l2 = strlen(str2)+1;

  l3 = l1 + l2; 


  str3 = (char *)malloc(l3);
  str3 = strcat(str1,str2);

  printf("%s\n",str3);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str3 = strcat(str1,str2);
```

`str1` points to a string literal and you can't concatenate (modify) to it. This causes *[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*.

```
strcpy(str3,str1);
strcat(str3,str2);
```

You have to ensure `str3` was allocated with enough memory.

And,

casting the [malloc return could be dangerous](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

Use a standard prototype for `main()` such as: `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char*argv[])`

Comment: Thank you, point noted!
However, 
`strcpy(str3,str1);`
`strcpy(str3,str2);`
gives the output as Front, how do I concatenate (Output: UnitedFront) using pointers?

Comment: The 2nd one should be `strcat` instead of `strcpy` to concatenate them

Comment: @Doraj Thanks. Usual copy-paste mistake :)

Comment: Yes, i know that too well :)

Answer (score 3):

```
char *str1 = "United";
char *str2 = "Front";
```

will place strings in the read-only parts of the memory and making `*str1`, `*str2`  a pointer to that, making any writing operation on this memory illegal.

So here you try to concatenate the string pointed by `*str2` to `*str1` which cause undefined behavior.

Instead `str3 = strcat(str1,str2);`

You can do like this

```
strcpy(str3,str1);
strcpy(str3+strlen(str3),str2);
```

Instead

Comment: +1. Strictly speaking, the string literals need not be stored in read-only memory. C standard says that modifying it is UB. Systems with no MMUs happily allow it. It's OK (valid) to modify it in pre-standard C :)

Comment: @BlueMoon Thanks for clarification and already i given you +1 :).

Answer (score 0):

Have a buffer ( str3 ) of size ( str1 + str2 + 1).

Use memcpy to get the required content.

```
memcpy(str3, str1, 6);
memcpy( str3 + 6, str2, 5 );
```

Add a null ('\0') value to the end of the string.